# Nullable bool with ClientTemplate Kendo Grid

Tags: c#, kendo-grid

I want to display text depending on a nullable bool which is `MyBool` (Bool?).

My code was:
`columns.Bound(p => p.MyBool).ClientTemplate("#= MyBool ? 'Yes' : 'No' #")`
But i have an error:

> ClientTemplate does not accept Bool? type

Do I have to convert it to a non-nullable boolean?

Comment: ... And if `MyBool` is null? What should `ClientTemplate()` display?

Comment: it should display empty text, i put it in the conditions but the problem is that ClientTemplate dont accept the Bool? type independantly of the code into the "#.. #"

Comment: I am not familar with KendoUI however you can't use a ternary operator with a nullable boolean. Take the following example. `bool? test = null; var output = test ? "yes" : "no; //// won't compile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried MyBool.Value if it is not null?

```
MyBool.HasValue() && MyBool.Value
```

Comment: yes that's it!! so the correct code is: columns.Bound(p => p.MyBool.HasValue).ClientTemplate("#= MyBool ? 'Yes' : 'No' #")
Thank you so much @majid

Comment: Perfect, just make sure you are checking the MyBool value as well, because it may have value but the value could be false.